# Does OpenThread work with Google's Nest app?

Tags: nest-api, openthread

Given an OpenThread border router (pi+nRF52840) and a Google Nest Aware "bundle", will the Thread network integrate with the Nest app on my iPhone?

May other thread devices (maybe not Nest) be added and viewed in the Google Nest app?

Kind regards
Graeme

Answer (score 0):

OpenThread is not sufficient for integrating with the Google Nest mobile app. Thread provides IPv6 connectivity. However, the Google Nest app requires application-layer protocols to communicate with compatible devices.